# How can I invert this current control?

Tags: led, current, control, npn

Below circuit is an emitter follower supplying current to an LED. A DAQ board is outputting 0-10VDC voltage to the base and cannot supply more than 5mA. Thats why the LED is not directly hoked up to the DAQ output. In the below circuit increasing DAQ analog voltage output will increase LED current hence the brightness. But I want to invert this adding another transistor or using another transistor.

How can I invert this so that 10V DAQ output will make LED dark and 0V will make it bright?

[image]

How can we invert it by adding another transistor? Or maybe a PNP? But DAQ should be safe not loaded.

Comment: Why can't you just reverse the numbers you send to the DAQ/DAC?

Comment: Because the softwarewise adjustment is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PNP transistor instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6VEmr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the LED supply voltage cannot be more than about 2 V higher than the maximum voltage of the DAQ output. With any higher voltage, the LED will not be completely dark when the DAQ is at its maximum voltage.

Note also that this requires the DAQ to *sink* current from the base of the transistor. This current will be a small fraction of the LED current — with a maximum LED current of about 20 mA, the base current will be on the order of 20-40 µA.

Comment: How bout using another NPN? It is hard to find 10V supply, I have 12V

Comment: See my update above. You get about 2V of "headroom" because of the Vf of the LED combined with the BE drop of the transistor.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. But would be great if you also can add darlington version with two NPN

Comment: I dont wanna damage the DAQ

Comment: I can't respond to that unless you identify the specific DAQ you're using.

Comment: http://www.mccdaq.com/pci-data-acquisition/PCI-DAS6036.aspx Analog Output of this DAQ

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/specs/pci-das603x-spec.pdf) says that it can drive +/-5 mA, so you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faLdVM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simulation shows a nearly linear run from about 20mA to 0mA when V1 changes from 0v to 10V.

So, 0V is maximum brightness, and 10V is off.  At 10V the simulation shows some microAmperes, so you might still see it glow in a VERY dark room but I don't think you can see it normally.

Comment: when I simulate your circuit it is not linear in all 0-10V range

Comment: See here (voltage is blue current s green): http://postimg.org/image/s57hgvf2f/

Comment: Then try a lower value for R3.  The performance depends on the gain of the transistor, and you will probably have to adjust things a bit to match the transistor you use.